# Control Internet Explorer with C#

Tags: c#, browser, web-scraping

There is a webpage that has Input textfields.

I want to launch the page

```
Process.Start("http://nameofdomain.com")
```

The question is how can I enter data into the fields and submit the form?

UPDATE -

I do not need to show/render any pages to the user.

The purpose is to allow users to change their password with minimal effort. Our current setup is

1. User navigates to site on Intranet (http://intranetsite/password)
2. The user is asked to input their Windows user name (firstName.lastName)
3. The user is asked to input their current password (or answer security questions if they exist)
4. The user is asked to click a link (choose between change password or change security questions)
5. The final page is a confirmation page which tells the user which passwords have been changed sucessfully. They have several accounts on our network. Each account has different password rules
   One system may require the password can't repeat again for the last 90 passwords. Another system requires the password to be exactly 8 characters. My application checks to see if the password rules are correct. I can't check the password history. Therefore the final page would be necessary or I'd have to parse the HTML and indicate the error.

Comment: if you are working in a windowed application like windows forms, I think you would have better control by embedding the WebBrowser control in your application UI and navigate it to the required url. or you find a very general solution, consider that a call to Process.Start("http://nameofdomain.com") could also open FireFox or Chrome...

Comment: Do you actually have to show the page, or is it ok if the HTTP request of the filled forms is sent without actually rendering the page?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better not to launch the browser window but create a `HTTP POST` request?

Comment: Well we could but it's a little complicated. On the local intranet site, the first page asks the user to input their username. The second page asks for their password (current). The 3rd page contains links that need to be clicked before they are  provided a final page (where they need to enter a new password twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (by far) is **WatiN** @ http://watin.org/. I tried Selenium and could never make it work smoothly (maybe it has got better since). WatiN's documentation is oriented towards automated testing, but you can do without the testing code/libaries, and it supports **Firefox** and **Chrome** too. For example:

```
using WatiN.Core;
using WatiN.Core.Interfaces;
using WatiN.Core.Logging;
using WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers;
```

...

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to import any classes to use WaitN?

Comment: Nope. All you need is to add a reference to `WatiN.Core.dll` to your project, then add the `using` directives that I just added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into Web Browser Automation tools like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), they have a C# driver to interact with and automate the browser.